# "Долина рек", "населения страны". Главное и зависимое слово

Tags: синтаксис

Пожалуйста, помогите найти главное и зависимое слово в словосочетаниях *долина рек, населения страны.*

Comment: Очень странные у вас сочетания. Первое подразумевает, что долина одна, а рек - две или больше. А второе - это или родительный падеж, либо неправильная форма. Слово "население" множественного числа не имеет. Вы точно эти сочетания правильно написали?

Comment: «Длина рек» и «для населения страны», может быть.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу трудностей при их определении

(что?)долина(какая? чего?) рек,

(чего?)населения(какого? чего?) страны.